# iOS5: When I set the region of a MKMapView it just shows a blue box

Tags: objective-c, ios5, mkmapview

When I display my map I wish to show the user's location in the centre and a span of approx. 5k distance around the user. My code is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
  mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
  MKUserLocation *userLocation = mapView.userLocation;
  MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
                            userLocation.location.coordinate, 5000, 5000);
  [mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
}
```

The result is that after the call to `setRegion` the map now shows as an empty blue box that can not be scrolled or zoomed. I thought for a while it might be displaying the ocean but that does not seem to be the case as the map itself won't scroll. I have tried setting the distances to everything from 50m to 25000m with the same effect. If I *don't* call `setRegion` then a zoomed out map of the world shows up fine with the user location highlighted as expected.

After browsing some related questions on this I also tried inserting the following line:

```
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

and replacing the setRegion message as follows:

```
[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:NO];
```

But that just goes me the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to follow up on this I added some logging and the `region` is being created ok, centred at 0,0 with a span of approx 5000 x 5000m give or take, and the `adjustedRegion` ends up with a span of 7500m x 5900m which is also fair enough. But if I simply `[mapView setCentreCoordinate:userLocation.location.coordinate];` the world map shows up fine, but with the blue dot right off to the far left and above California. Funny but I thought 0,0 was above Greenwich in England.

Comment: Greenwich is at 0 longitude, then head straight south to the equator to get 0 latitude and you'll find yourself at (0,0) off the coast of Africa staring at a lot of blue sea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't waited for your mapView to get a valid location. If you set your controller to be the delegate of the mapView and then tell the mapview to `showUserLocation` you'll eventually get a call back `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` that will have the coordinates for the device. I suspect the reason you think you can't zoom or pan is that (0,0) is waaaaay out in the ocean and everything is blue. It could also be that your MKMapView hasn't been set up to allow touch interaction such as pinch and zoom so check your xib has all the right checkboxes turned on